# Finding label-value pairs and capturing value Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to find values associated with labels that partly match a string.  The block of source looks like this:

```
    <dt>
        Loose Ones
    </dt>
    <dd>
        8.00
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Loose Fives
    </dt>
    <dd>
        15.00
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Envelope Ones
    </dt>
    <dd>
        0.00
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Envelope Fives
    </dt>
        25.00
    <dd>
```

I want to find all labels that contain 'Loose' and capture the associated value then total it into a value.  Jquery must have a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your `dt` elements, find those who match, then find the closest `dd` element and parse it's inner value to a number.

```
var sum = 0;

$.each($('dt'), function(){
  if($(this).text().indexOf("Loose") != -1)
  {
    var dd = $(this).next('dd');
    var n = parseFloat(dd.text());
    sum = sum + n;
  }
});
console.log(sum);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stjv1n3z/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's `contains()` selector to filter the `dt` tags with value 'Loose' and then use `.next()` to get to the `dd` element.

```
var sum =0;

$('dt:contains("Loose")').each(function()
{
    if(!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).next('dd').text())))
      sum += parseFloat($(this).next('dd').text());
});

alert(sum);
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ve1jo4oo/

Comment: Thanks to MorKadash and DinoMyte for the replies. I used DinoMyte's answer and it worked beautifully.